# My loop does not work for finding the System Time Millis in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does my loop not work?

I'm trying to increment by 5 and the output the time it took to increment with the linear method

```
for(n=5;n<=10;n=n+5) {

    long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(startTime);

    System.out.println("\nOddanaci(" + n +")\n" );

    linear(n);

    long endTime= System.currentTimeMillis();

    long diff= endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("\n\nThe Total time it took to run this program is\n"+diff);

}
```

my output

```
Please enter the a non-negative value to find its Oddonacci sequence: 3

Here is the Oddonacci(3) sequence

1 1 1

The method has been called 1 times.

1537756698523

Oddanaci(5)

1 1 1 3 5

The Total time it took to run this program is

1

1537756698524

Oddanaci(10)

1 1 1 3 5 9 17 31 57 105

The Total time it took to run this program is

0
```

Why does it output as zero? Doesn't n iterate?

Comment: Perhaps it runs faster then 1ms? Try adding a sleep or running multiple times to confirm.

Comment: try `System.nanoTime()`  for more precise time difference.

Comment: You'll need to find the average time over many, many iterations.  Start with 10,000 iterations and keep increasing by factors of 10 until total runtime is on the order of a minute.  At the point, either the average runtime will have started converging toward a consistent lower limit (or you will have run out of patience for further testing) and you'll then have a **rough approximation** of the per-iteration runtime.